# Why WebElement and List<WebElement> are processed not in the similar way via xpath and List is always null?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, findby, thucydides

I'm using Thucydides 0.9.229 with Selenium shipped with it. To obtain some webelements I try to get them via List

```
@FindAll({@FindBy(xpath = "//div[text()='Расположение']/../../td[2]//input[@type='text']")})
private List<WebElement> placement;
```

with no result, the placement is returned null, while here

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[text()='Расположение']/../../td[2]//input[@type='text']")})
private WebElement placement;
```

there placement is not null, but the correct webelement handled well. As far as I understand, the firs example should return the 1-value list anyway, but even more values if there were some additional elements fitting the criteria. So, what is wrong, why I can't get the list of webelements there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue with @FindAll, and it also returns null.

However, you can use @FindBy for list of elements too. It may be used to mark a field on a Page Object to indicate an element or a list of elements.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[text()='Расположение']/../../td[2]//input[@type='text']")})
private List<WebElement> placement;
```